# How to change the background color of CIPAddressCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, background-color

I tried to change the background color and text color of the IP Address Control in MFC.
Once, I have changed the text color and background color, but the points between the Edit controls are not displayed.
My code is as follows:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(KIPAddressCtrl, CIPAddressCtrl)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// KIPAddressCtrl message handlers

HBRUSH KIPAddressCtrl::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    m_brush.DeleteObject();
    m_brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));

    CRect rc;
    CWindowDC dc(this);
    GetWindowRect(&rc);
    
    dc.Draw3dRect(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), RGB(0, 0, 255), RGB(0, 0, 255));   
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));  
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 255, 0));
    
    return (HBRUSH)m_brush;
}

void KIPAddressCtrl::OnPaint()
{
    CRect rc;
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    GetClientRect(&rc);     
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rc, RGB(255, 255, 0));

    //CIPAddressCtrl::OnPaint();
}
```

My result is

[image]

But I want to

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: You don't need to `DeleteObject` the `m_brush` and recreate it every time the workflows passes in `OnCtlColor`. Just put the initialization on an initialization function like `Create` or something similar and you will not even need to care about `DeleteObject`, as it will be automatically done in the destructor.

Comment: Why are you providing an `OnPaint` override? Why are you calling `Draw3dRect` with two identical colors? Why are you ignoring the device context passed into your `OnCtlColor` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the separators disappear is because of the `FillSolidRect` call in the `KIPAddressCtrl::OnPaint()` handler, overwriting anything the default implementation had done.

Coloring the [IP Address Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ip-address-control-reference) the way you want isn't supported. While the embedded [Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) request a color from their parent (the IP Address Control), the control itself will not send respective messages to its parent that would allow you to apply your customization.

In other words: While the four embedded edit controls can be customized, the area not covered by the edit controls cannot. That's unfortunate, but it is what it is.